# LocalNotification icon not showing on CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

EDITED: I believe this question is NOT a duplicate of other questions since it applies specifically to CodenameOne , and how it uses the android libraries, not just to the android libraries themselves.  I believe that either a) I need help in how to use the CodenameOne classes correctly, or b) the CodenameOne classes needs to be updated to work with Android 5.1.1.

The problem: When I use 'scheduleLocalNotification' with CodenameOne compiled to Android, the notification works but the message contains only white squares where I would expect the application icon.  My test code is very like that in the documentation for `Class LocalNotification` in codenameone:

```
LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
n.setId("LnMessage");
n.setAlertTitle("Alert Title");
n.setAlertBody("Alert detailed message");
Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
  n, System.currentTimeMillis()+10, LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE
);
```

Full example: https://gist.github.com/twilkinson/893d96bcf84698e0c694775b99174460

Here are a couple of screen shots from the Android device that illustrate my problem.

Image 1

[image: image 1]

Image 2

[image: image 2]

I've tried placing an image file `alert-image.png` in the project beside `theme.res` and adding the line

```
n.setAlertImage("alert-image.png");
```

but that doesn't seem to help.

My device is a Nexus 4 with Android version 5.1.1

Can someone point me to an example somewhere of how to make this work?

**UPDATED:**
At Shai's suggestion (below), I added an image file ic_stat_notify.png to the native/android folder (white on transparency).  The result was no change to the notification area image ("Image 1" above), but the new image showed in the expanded notification drawer ("Image 3" below).

Image 3

[image: image 3]

Comment: Place a 24x24 icon named `ic_stat_notify.png` under the `native/android` folder of the app. The icon can be white with transparency areas. The build server picks up this image and uses it as the notification icon if found on the project.

Comment: Shai, thanks, that got me part of the way.  The ic_stat_notify.png image now shows up in the expanded notification message (2nd image above) but not in the status bar (1st image above).  I looked at the source code for createAndroidNotification() in impl/android/LocalNotificationPublisher.java on github, and it looks like it should work, but I'm still getting the white square in the status bar.

Comment: Can you update the screenshots, I'll have to check on that

Comment: I've looked into it a bit and it seems the behavior is a bit problematic, can you please file an issue in git?

Comment: I've updated the OP and filed a github Issue (#2068).  Thanks.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of what I understood, I thought the titlebar one was fixed

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know/use the correct terminology in my comment - I think I got it right when I updated the OP. (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: It's very possible you did use the right terminology, it's just that an image is much clearer ;-)